# jquery mobile how remove the grey round circle on icon

Tags: jquery-mobile, icons

I build my first phonegap Jquery Appl
Im changing my icon using this class

```
.ui-icon-myapp-email {
    background-image: url("app-icon-email.png");
}
```

This custom icon is for a list view , and i try to remove the round grey background load
Also my picture is a bit big for the shape
I was playing with the .ui-icon but doesnt work
Cant find the class

I just wanna my custom arrow picture full size on a white background list no round no circle box shape
Maybe there is an attribute or via css to make that
thanks

Answer (score 16):

If you are using jQuery v 1.4.0 + then you just need to add the class `.ui-nodisc-icon` to your link element to remove that annoying circle. You will not need to edit any css or write any overrides.

Answer (score 9):

Late to the party here, but a simple answer is to add

```
background-color: transparent;
box-shadow: none;
```

to your custom class name, so:

```
.ui-icon-myapp-email {
    background-color: transparent;
    box-shadow: none;
}
```

is all you need.

Answer (score 4):

With JQuery Mobile 1.3, now all you have to do is **add the class "ui-nodisc-icon"**, no need to mess around with the CSS.

from [JQuery Website](http://blog.jquerymobile.com/page/2/):

"If you don’t need the dark circle behind the icons, simply **add the ui-nodisc-icon to the element or its container** to remove the icon background."

Answer (score 2):

This should work.

```
.ui-icon-myapp-email {
    background:transparent; /* or none */
    background-image: url("app-icon-email.png");
    /* The following border radius rules will override the circle around your icon */
    -moz-border-radius: 0px;
    -webkit-border-radius:0px;
    border-radius:0px;
}
/* To fix the size issue override the .ui-icon height */
.ui-icon{
    width:14px;
    height:20px;
}
```

Comment: I was trying this way first but it give a white hole but my icon dissapear behind z-index & overflow doesnt help...thanks

Comment: What size is your custom icon?

Comment: I added the css necessary to get rid of the rounded corners.

Comment: Hi codaniel thanks helping i really appreciate following the image http://img29.imageshack.us/img29/8899/iconarrow.png , the icon is 14px *20 px...and appear true the round hole ...was trying z-index overflow attribute but doesn't help...i also change border radius but not working...i couldd make it smaller but doesn't feet client design approval...thanks

Comment: try the ui-icon class i added

Answer (score 0):

Overrides the icon disc color to white.

```
.ui-icon,
.ui-icon-searchfield:after {
    background: #fff /*{global-icon-color}*/;
    background: rgba(255,255,255,1) /*{global-icon-disc}*/;
    background-image: url(images/icons-18-white.png) /*{global-icon-set}*/;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    -moz-border-radius: 9px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 9px;
    border-radius: 9px;
}
```

Icon size is specified in `ui-icon` class which defaults to `18px`.

```
.ui-icon {
    width: 19px;
    height: 19px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks but My icon now appear in fact in a white background but a little cut because behind the round box , what css is in charge of the round hole ..firebug doesnt give me the info and z-index seems not helping

Comment: It is in the `ui-icon` class.

Answer (score 0):

For those of you looking to have just an icon for the button - I found this article to be very useful! I followed the "Reset the button theme" and "Icon-only buttons" sections to get the effect that I needed.

http://appcropolis.com/blog/advanced-customization-jquery-mobile-buttons/

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue, using:

```
background-color:transparent;
```

if you want to add color in background you can use:

```
background: url(yourimage.png) repeat;
```